# R - run function by loop

Tags: r, loops

I have this dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(nr = seq(1, 200))
```

Lets say that I have function like this

```
mult <-
  function(x = 1) {
    
    return(
      df %>% 
        mutate(
          result = nr*x,
          x = x
          )
    )
    
  }
```

Is there better way how to put number to x parameter, lets say from -999 to 999. And bind everything together to single dataframe?

```
result <-
  rbind(
    mult(x = 1),
    mult(x = 2),
    mult(x = 3),
    mult(x = 4)
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(1:4, mult))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `purrr::map_dfr` with your set-up:

```
library(purrr)
result2 = map_dfr(1:4, mult)
all.equal(result2, result)
# [1] TRUE
```

You could, of course, use `-999:999` in place of `1:4`.

Alternately, you could use `outer` (which multiplies by default, but you can specify any binary operation) instead of your `mult` function, something like this:

```
result3 <- cbind(df, result = c(outer(df$nr, 1:4)), x = rep(1:4, each = nrow(df)))
all.equal(result, result3)
# [1] TRUE
```